# How do you delete an alternate profile on LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin, profile

I created a second language profile on LinkedIn which is becoming too much of a hassle to keep up to date. I also no longer need a profile in that language.
This was created on the same account as my primary profile (it is not a second account).

How can I delete this secondary profile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete a secondary language profile:

Click **Profile** at the top of your home page.
Click on **Edit Profile** just below.
Select the **language** from the Profile dropdown in the upper right.
Click **Delete this profile**.
Click **Yes, Delete Profile**.

Answer (score 2):

Annoyingly, [you can't](http://linkedin.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/linkedin.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=1717&p_created=1243880193&p_sid=P_-KJJbk&p_accessibility=0&p_redirect=&p_lva=&p_sp=cF9zcmNoPTEmcF9zb3J0X2J5PSZwX2dyaWRzb3J0PSZwX3Jvd19jbnQ9MzkyLDM5MiZwX3Byb2RzPTAmcF9jYXRzPSZwX3B2PSZwX2N2PSZwX3BhZ2U9MSZwX3NlYXJjaF90ZXh0PWRlbGV0ZSBsYW5ndWFnZSBwcm9maWxl&p_li=&p_topview=1):

> Profiles cannot be removed once they have been created.

Comment: This is no longer true. They recently added the ability to do this.

Comment: @GoodPerson I've been trying to set my 'secondary language' profile as 'primary' and its apparently impossible.